# Adding spaces to items in list (Python)

Tags: python, string, list, space

I'm a Python noob and I need some help for a simple problem.

What I need to do is create a list with 3 items and add spaces before and after every item.

For example: `l1 = ['a', 'bb', 'c']`
should be transformed into: `['  a  ','  bb  ','  c  ']`

I was trying to write something like this:

```
lst = ['a', 'bb', 'c']
for a in lst:
    print '  a  '
```

...and so on for the other elements, but I get a syntax error.
Can anyone suggest me a working way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As always, use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#list-displays):

```
lst = [' {0} '.format(elem) for elem in lst]
```

This applies a [string formatting operation](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings) to each element, adding the spaces. If you use python 2.7 or later, you can even omit the `0` in the replacement field (the curly braces).

Answer (score 7):

```
[ ' {} '.format(x) for x in lst ]
```

EDIT for python 3.6+:

you can use f-strings instead, see docs: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/

the example above would look like:

```
[ f' {x} ' for x in lst ]
```

Comment: This will give you `ValueError: zero length field name in format`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: No it won't. Not in Python 2.7 where I tried it in any case.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid <2.7, yes. There make it ``' {0} '``. Pre 2.7, automatically numbering items wasn't possible.

Comment: `' {0} '.format(x)` would work in all versions where `.format()` is supported, hence a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = ['a', 'bb', 'c']  
lst = [' ' + x + ' ' for x in lst]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [44]: l1 = ['a', 'bb', 'c']

In [45]: [' %s '%x for x in l1]
Out[45]: [' a ', ' bb ', ' c ']
```

Answer (score 1):

Indent your python code first!
And then:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
lst2 = [' ' + a + ' ' for a in lst]
print lst2
```

Comment: You'd be better off using the `.format()` method, or at a pinch the `%` string formatting operator, instead of concatenation. It is much more efficient.

Comment: This worked perfectly for every string I put in, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
lst = [' ' + x + ' ' for x in ['a', 'bb', 'c']]
```

Comment: You'd be better off using the `.format()` method, or at a pinch the `%` string formatting operator, instead of concatenation. It is much more efficient.

Comment: You can just replace `['a', 'bb', 'c']` with any other list of strings, or with a variable containing a list (e.g., your `lst`).

Comment: I agree, using `.format()` is a more efficient approach in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> lst = ['a', 'bb', 'c']
>>> 
>>> [' {} '.format(x) for x in lst]
[' a ', ' bb ', ' c ']
>>>
```