# How to create whitespace between certain list elements?

Tags: python, list

I found a post asking about how to create whitespace in *all* list elements ([Adding spaces to items in list (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892698/adding-spaces-to-items-in-list-python)), but I haven't found any posts asking about how to create whitespace in only *specific* elements of a list.

I'm wondering how to create a space between certain element characters in a list.

If I have a list like this:

```
lst = ['a', 'bb', 'c', 'bb']
```

How can I make a new list with a space between all 'bb' occurrences in a list to look like this?:

```
lst_new = ['a', 'b b', 'c', 'b b']
```

I've tried using .replace('bb', 'b" "b'), but I get 'b' and 'b' as separate list elements. Is there a specific notation for "whitespace" in Python? Or is there another way to approach this?

Comment: `[ 'b b' if x == 'bb' else x for x in lst]` ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. "I've tried using .replace('bb', 'b" "b'), but I get 'b' and 'b' as separate list elements." This sounds like you tried converting the list to a string first, and then doing string replacement on it. If you do this, then you *still have a string*, ***not*** *a list*. It is important to understand what data types are, and why they are important and useful.

Comment: Can you write code that gives you the correct result for a single list element? Can you think of a way to repeat code with each element of a list? If you put those two things together, does that solve the problem?

Comment: I think you are forgetting that .replace() is not standalone; e.g a = a.replace() instead of just a.replace(). Also make sure you do replace("bb", "b b")

Comment: "I found a post asking about how to create whitespace in all list elements" [edit]ing the post to include a link might make it easier to understand the problem. It would also be a good idea to show the *exact* code you tried for this task - make sure that someone else can copy and paste it and see the same effect you do.

Comment: I don't get why .replace('bb', 'b" "b') doesn't work for you

Comment: @d.b Strings are sequences, so no need to cast into `list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lst = ['a', 'bb', 'c', 'dd']

lst_new = []

for elem in lst:
    if len(elem) > 1:
        lst_new.append(' '.join(list(elem)))
    else:
        lst_new.append(elem)
    
print(lst_new)
```

Here's a very simple and easy to understand way to do it. The main idea is to check if the length of the `elem` is greater than 1, then use `list` to "split" the string. You can then join the string with a whitespace by using `join`.